# "..." operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I found the following case in javascript. I don't understand '...' operator mean here. I search it on the Google, but I did not get anything about it. Is there any other usage for this operator? Can someone help me out?

```js
var x= [1,2,3];
var y = [4,5,6];

var z = [...x, ...y]; // z will be [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `...` operator is called the Spread Operator or Spread syntax. See the [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) about it.

Comment: [`...` is **not** an operator!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196)

Comment: @Felix Kling if it's not an operator, what is it?  I ask because it's filed under expressions & operators in the MDN docs.

Comment: ah wait... it's actually just called _spread syntax_

Comment: @Pineda: It's a punctuator.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Cool man, thanks.  Was just googling this to find a reputable definition.  May I ask what yours is (book, article...)?

Comment: @Pineda: The ECMAScript specification. `...` is simply part of various constructs, just like `,` is, but it's not a "thing" on its own.

Comment: @Felix Kling:  I just noticed that in  "You don't know Javscript: ES6 & Beyond", they refer to the `...` as the spread or rest _operator_.  Will this book and the MDN, it's understandable why the lay-folk are confuseth

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks for the explanation.  I guess this is just something to with what people find pleasant in parlance as a name vs the name's technical accuracy.  A spread operator sounds 'nicer' than just 'the spread'.  Maybe we could lobby for it to be called "triple dot"!

Comment: @Pineda: The spec actually gives names to most of `...`'s use cases. E.g. in this situation, we are talking about a *spread element*, whereas when used in destructuring, it's a *rest element*. This also makes it clearer that the `...` does different things in different contexts. See the link in my first comment as well. Basically I want to make people understand that `...` is not a thing on it's own, its part of the array literal syntax, destructuring syntax, function call syntax, etc.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Many thanks for the explanation.  Kudos in your aim to _spread_ the word 8-)

Comment: @FelixKling We could also simply call it *token*, but "punctuator" is nice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a way of thinking which makes it very easy to understand and remember how '...' works.

```
var arr = [1,2,3] // this is arr which is the array
```

on the other hand

```
...arr            // this is whatever inside arr, which is 1,2,3
```

So you can also think of it as taking what is inside of an array.

---

Note that by its own, ...arr is not a valid syntax. You can use it in 
many ways , two of them coming to my mind are :

1 - Pass what is inside an array to a function

```
var arr = [ 1,2,3 ]
var myFunc = function(a,b,c) {
  console.log(a,b,c)
}
myFunc(..arr)   // logs 1 2 3

myFunc(1,2,3)   // logs 1 2 3
```

2 - Take what is inside of an array and use them in another array.

```
var arr = [ 1,2,3 ]
var foo = [ ...arr, 4,5,6 ] // now foo is [ 1,2,3,4,5,6 ]
```

Comment: Object spread syntax is not available in ES7 either.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Couldn t find much about it and deleted the part about it.

Comment: However `...arr` on its own doesn't mean anything. `...arr` has different meaning depending on whether it is used e.g. inside an array literal or inside destructuring. That's why it doesn't make sense to look at `...` on its own.

Comment: Is my answer misleading ? I can not think of a scenario where this analogy doesn t work @Felix Kling

Comment: In `[foo, ...bar] = baz;`, `...bar` means something different. `...arr` on its own doesn't mean anything, it's a syntax error.