# square of two arrays numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Function that compares and array with its numerically sorted version in ascending order. Return the sum of the square differences between each term of the two arrays.

Expample:

For the array a= [2,3,1], the sorted version is b=[1,2,3],

.the sum of the square differences is (2-1)2 + (3-2)2 + (1-3)2 = 6

. or in terms of array elements (a[0]-b[0])2  + (a[1]-b[1])2 + (a[2]+b[2])2 = 6

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 1];

function myFunction(arr) {
  var newarr = [];
  var a = arr;
  var b = arr;
  var sum = 0;
  b.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    var sub = a[i] - b[i];

    sub = sub * 2;
    sum += sub;
    newarr.push(sum);

  }
  return newarr;

}

console.log(myFunction(arr));
```

Comment: Why do you do `var a = arr` and `var b = arr`? Why not just `arr.sort()`?

Comment: `a` and `b` are the same array. So `var sub = a[i] - b[i]` always sets it to `0`.

Comment: Array types are pass by reference. So the change to `b` applied to `a` since they share the same reference, this is why the subtraction is always `0`.

Comment: `sub = sub * 2` is not how you square a number. `sub = sub * sub` squares it.

Comment: i was thing a  = arr store old array and b = array b.short() so i will get old and new array.  but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning arrays doesn't make copies. So `a`, `b`, and `arr` are all the same array, and you're just subtracting a number from itself, always getting zero. You need to make a copy of the array in the other variable.

You're also not squaring correctly, it should be `sub * sub`, not `sub * 2`.

You're supposed to return `sum`. There's no need for `newArr`.

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 1];

function myFunction(arr) {
  var sorted = [...arr]; // make copy
  sorted.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });

  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    var sub = arr[i] - sorted[i];
    sub = sub * sub;
    sum += sub;
  }
  return sum;

}

console.log(myFunction(arr));
```

Comment: Do we need callback inside sort?

Comment: Yes. The default sort compares as strings, not numbers.

Comment: what is the meaning of "..." ...arr

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731996/operator-in-javascript